# How to add Unicode symbols into FPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, unicode, fpdf

I’ve tried lots of times to add the bullet styles into my `FPDF` document.
I wanna add the different bullet styles like these :

```
● Filled circle (&#x26AB;)
○ Unfilled circle (&#x26AA;)
■ Filled square (&#x25A0;)
```

I tried to put it by using these functions :

```
utf8_decode 
utf8_encode 
mb_convert_encoding 
html_entity_decode
htmlspecialchars_decode 
WriteHTML 
str_replace 
get_html_translation_table
iconv
```

I have also tried using UTF-8 `(hex, dec, oct, Character CP1251, etc..)`.
Eventually, I put those all bullet styles in direct way without translation or `encoding/decoding`

But all my attempts “ didn’t work ” . 
Could anybody help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I assume FPDF is http://www.fpdf.org/ ? If so you should add the tag `PHP`. And what does your actual output look like?

Comment: Yes, I did. I was using the images instead of the unicode symbols and call it by php. Thank you. @MarkRansom